# unable to read data from textfile and put it to structs and union to get output in another textfile and output window

Tags: c, file, struct, io, unions

I just started learning the C language and have problems with structures and input/output stream understanding. I am trying to make a code that will read existing information in the created text file, input it into structures that are united by the union, and copy it to newly created through the code text file. I also try to make this information appear in the output window.
Below is an example of code I tried to make, but it gives me a strange output and I'm not sure what I suppose to do here.From the text file I'm trying to read the info of student ID, name, school status, how many times awarded with scholarship, phone, age, cgpa, if studying abroad now or not. My file looks like this:

name/  ID/      age/ scholarship/ schoolstat/ abroad/ address/                    phone/      cgpa

mark/ 20091111/ 20/   1/          Yes/        No/     city,district,street,house/ 1234567890/ 3.0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


typedef struct{

    char name[20];
    char mail[30];
    int mobile;
    }PROFESSOR;

typedef struct{

    char name[20];
    char address[50];
    char schoolstat[10];
    int scholarship[5];
    char abroad[10];
    int phone;
    int age;    
    int ID;
    float cgpa;
    }STUDENT;

typedef struct{

    char type;
    union {
        PROFESSOR prof;
        STUDENT stu;
    }u;
    }PERSON;
 
// Driver program

int main () {

    FILE *infile, *ofp;
    PERSON data[6];
    int i;
    char name[20];
    char address[50];
    char schoolstat[10];
    int scholarship[5];
    char abroad[10];
    int phone;
    int age;    
    int ID;
    float cgpa;
    
    infile = fopen ("inputfile.txt", "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    ofp=fopen("outputfile.txt", "w");
    if(ofp==NULL){
        printf("output file open error!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    data[0].type = 'p';
    strcpy(data[0].u.prof.name, "Sam");
    strcpy(data[0].u.prof.mail, "ssss@mail.com");
    data[0].u.prof.mobile = 1234567;
    
    data[1].type = 's';
    data[2].type = 's';
    data[3].type = 's';
    data[4].type = 's';
    data[5].type = 's';
    
    int total = 0;
    int total_age=0;
    int newline=0;
    
    int res;
    char c;
    int i;
    while(1){
        res=fscanf(infile, "%d %d %d %d %s %s %s %d %f\n", name, &ID, &age, &scholarship, &schoolstat, &abroad, &address, &phone, &cgpa);
        if(res==EOF) break;
        fprintf(ofp, "%d %s %d %d %s %s %s %d %f\n", ID, name, age, scholarship, schoolstat, abroad, address, phone, cgpa);
        i++;
        if(i==5) break;
        total = total + cgpa;
        total_age = total_age + age;
        for(newline=0; newline<res; newline++){
            if(name[c]=='\0'){
                newline++;
            }
        }   
    }
    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
        switch(data[i].type){
            case 'p':
                printf("professor %s\n", data[i].u.prof.name);
                printf("%s, %d\n", data[i].u.prof.mail, data[i].u.prof.mobile);
                break;
            case 's':
                printf("student %s %d %d %d %s %s %s %d %f\n", data[i].u.stu.name, data[i].u.stu.age, data[i].u.stu.ID, data[i].u.stu.scholarship, data[i].u.stu.schoolstat, data[i].u.stu.abroad,
                 data[i].u.stu.address, data[i].u.stu.phone, data[i].u.stu.cgpa);
                break;
                }
                printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Number of lines: %d", newline);
    // close file
    fclose (infile);
    fclose(ofp);
 
    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any help!

now output is like the next:
professor Sam
ssss@mail.com, 1234567

student  0 0 6486936    0 0.000000

student  0 0 6487068    0 0.000000

student  0 0 6487200    0 0.000000

student  0 0 6487332    0 0.000000

Number of lines: 0

Comment: Could you please post what output you get ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Now my output in file looks like this: 0  838861107 6486576 x  ??0 0.000000
0  838861107 6486576 x  ??0 0.000000
0  838861107 6486576 x  ??0 0.000000
0  838861107 6486576 x  ??0 0.000000
0  838861107 6486576 x  ??0 0.000000
0  838861107 6486576 x  ??0 0.000000
0  838861107 6486576 x  ??0 0.000000
0  838861107 6486576 x  ??0 0.000000                                                                and in command window it became like this: professor Sam
ssss@mail.com, 1234567

0 0 6486920 00.000000
0 0 6487052 00.000000
0 0 6487184 00.000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format uses `'/'` as a separator.  Use `"%width[^/]"` to read a string token.

Use `" %n"` to record offset of scan, if it made it that far.

---

After a successful `fopen()` read a *line*

```
#define LINE_MAX 135    // Longest expected line
char line[LINE_MAX*2];  // Be generous and read even more
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, ofp)) {
```

Now parse it

```
  STUDENT st = { 0 };
  int n = 0;
  // Format broken up to help illustrate parsing
  sscanf(line, " %19[^/]" "/" "%d " "/" 
      "%d " "/" "%d " "/" 
      " %9[^/]" "/" " %4[^/]" "/" 
      " %49[^/]" "/" " %d " "/" 
      "%f " " %n",
      st.name, &st.ID,
      &st.age, &scholarship[0], 
      st.schoolstat, st.abroad,
      st.address, &st.phone,
      st.cgpa, &n);  
    // Check if scan completed with no extra trailing junk
    if (n == 0 || line[n] != '\0') {
      ; // Handle bad input
    } else {
      ;  Use input
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

### The answer

You're never initialising the values of `data[1]` to `data[5]`. In C variables with automatic storage duration aren't initialised and have an undefined value. You need to initialise them :

```c
data[1] = (PERSON){.type = 's', .u.stu = (STUDENT){0}};
data[2] = (PERSON){.type = 's', .u.stu = (STUDENT){0}};
data[3] = (PERSON){.type = 's', .u.stu = (STUDENT){0}};
data[4] = (PERSON){.type = 's', .u.stu = (STUDENT){0}};
data[5] = (PERSON){.type = 's', .u.stu = (STUDENT){0}};
```

---

### More details

In C there are multiple type of storage class : `static`, `auto`, `register` and `extern`. The most important to know are the static and automatic storage class specifiers. A static variable exists during the whole program execution and an automatic variable exists only while its context is being executed (when the program is inside a function for example).

By default, variables declared outside of a function body are static, and variable inside a function body are automatic. You can force a local variable to be stored statically by using the `static` keyword.

Most importantly, automatic variables aren't initialised when declared but they still point to a chunk of memory. This means that reading from a variable that hasn't been initialised will simply return garbage. That's probably what you are getting.